# Reading bus connections on a block diagram of an MCU

Tags: microcontroller, bus, diagram

I'm trying to read and route the clock bus of GPIOB of [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f303k8.pdf) MCU from its block diagram.

Normally another type of MCU block diagram is given as follows:

[image]

So above is easy for me to say GPIOB is connected to AHB1 bus which I route in yellow.

But in this case the block diagram is given as follows:

[image]

And I'm not able route the GPIOB to any of AHB. The peripheral register boundary addresses is given as:

[image]

So it seems GPIOB is connected to AHB2 bus.

My questions are:

1. Can someone show how to route this just by looking at the block diagram?
2. And does the term AHB bus include both "address bus" "clock bus" and "data bus"?

Comment: I'm guessing that there is no magic solution to 1 that you're missing - you simply can't tell purely from the block diagram which bus controls GPIOx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone show how to route this just by looking at the block
> diagram?

No, just use the address to write to the GPIO bus.

But the best thing to use the [HAL of the Cube Mx tool from STM](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html). You can use it to configure the GPIOS and generate code. If you don't want to use the HAL, you can still generate the code and follow the function calls and then write directly to the register (or trace it back and find the value of the register if you want to write everything from scratch.

If you want a more in depth view of the AHB bus, check the arm website.

[image]
Source: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0011/a/AMBA-AHB/Bus-interconnection?lang=en